# Execute an external .exe from a local .swf using a local XML Socket server (C#)

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3, localhost, daemon

I'm developing a game add-on/plugin which replaces a built in feature of an online game. The game loads an .swf therefore, my solution also has to be an swf for it to work 'in-game'.

I would *like* to be able to have the user press a button in the custom .swf I am making - and this would open an external application (amongst other things). I.e. if there was a button that said Notepad, it would open Notepad.exe on the machine.

My initial thinking was that i could have a XML Socket server 'daemon' runnning (c#) , which i could connect to with flash - however, as both the swf and the daemon are local, flash complained and gave this error:

```
"Error #2010: Local-with-filesystem SWF files are not permitted to use sockets."
```

The only way i know to fix this - is to change the security settings of flash - not very user friendly!

So! Any thoughts on how I could otherwise go about this? I was thinking a custom http server could do the trick (connected with URLRequest) although i'm not too sure.

Comment: You could look in to the possibility of packing your custom swf as an AIR application: http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html. It gives a far more permissive runtime environment, more opportunities like the ones you mention, than running a regular swf.

Comment: The problem with that is - it has to be an .swf that is loaded into the game. I've never used AIR but i presume it's not an .swf extension.

Comment: OK. If your custom swf is to be loaded into the game swf, then AIR is out of the question, that is correct. I think it will be hard to launch an external .exe in that case. If the .exe is something you develop, and the end user is required to install it, it could possibly be done by registering a custom protocol that your .exe is set to handle, and that can be called from ActionScript as URL's, like "myapp://command/start" or such. But I am far from sure that could work, I haven't tested it (from Flash) myself.

Comment: Oh wow, that could be really nice if it worked - I think lots of iPhone apps use that. Yes, the users have to download an installer which replaces the .swf for them, I guess I could add a daemon to the installer which could handle the custom protocol - perhaps flash could load a url on my server - which would redirect it accordingly to the custom one - a bit like what iTunes does? Do you think that could work?

Comment: Also, i've never registered a custom protocol before. Do you have any links you can recommend?

Comment: Could try the "file" protocol. Documentation on URI protocols are here for Adobe Air (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cba.html)

Comment: @Jonathan, no, I don't have any links and I haven't registered any protocols under Windows (that I recall, only on Mac OS and iOS). But I just now made a quick test doing navigateToURL(new URLRequest("skype://test")); from a locally run swf, and it works, starts Skype, without any security violation warnings or such.

Comment: @Dominic, I said above, AIR is out of the question, so unless that's available in a normal flash .swf, I wouldn't be able to use that. The custom protocol seems the best bet!

Comment: @Jonathan, cool, seems like you're doing something really rad. I've seen this to explain how to register a Windows app for URI protocols (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) but I've never done it for windows software development. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is possible to use an [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), which based on a [NPRuntime API](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/plugins/npruntime.html). You also may check a [fscommand function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html). Official tutorials recommend this technics for interaction with C/C++ code.